# Adding numbers with buttons

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a couple buttons. After you press one of the buttons for first time the sum should display the value of the button. Then when you press the other button (or the same one) both of the buttons values should add up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>simple calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">1</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">2</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">3</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">4</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">5</button>
<p>The sum: <span id="sum">0</span></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function sum(){

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what I should write in the script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  function sum(){
document.getElementById("sum").innerText=document.getElementById("sum").innerText*1+event.target.innerText*1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>simple calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">1</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">2</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">3</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">4</button>
<button onclick="sum()" type="button" name="button">5</button>
<p>The sum: <span id="sum">0</span></p>
```